# How to show week number in twitter bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I"m using twitter bootstrap datepicker . refer the link http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

I want to show week number like the following http://jsbin.com/omaqe/1/edit

I don't want to change the jquery plugin. I want to use only twitter bootstrap datepicker. How to show week number using this.

and

I want to show datepicker based on the culture. Please give me solution for this too..

Thank you for your effort to help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), there is an option called **`calendarWeeks`**(a boolean dataType), *Whether or not to show week numbers to the left of week rows.*

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    calendarWeeks: true
});
```

[image]

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GX82L/2/)

Comment: I need to display datepicker based on the culture. Is this possible ?

Comment: @Vijay are you taking about the localization?  Is this something you are trying http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GX82L/4/?

Comment: Based on the country, do week start date change ?. If it's so, then, How to show this ?

Comment: @Vijay you don't need to worry.  That is the speciality of localization.  Here is a list of locale in [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js/locales).  Hope you understand

Comment: I'm worrying to know the week number. Because if week start date change means, the week number of the year also will change I think.. (I'm asking logically.. don't have any proof)... If no, then please give me a detail. because i've to prove myself, if i'm going your way.. If my words are not polite, don't take it in serious. I'm new to english language..

Comment: @Vijay week number of the year won't change.

Answer (score 0):

In angular 9 you have to use the following;

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="dateRangePicker"
  bsDaterangepicker
  [(ngModel)]="my-model"
  [bsConfig]="{
    showWeekNumbers: false
  }"
  name="bsDaterangepicker"
/>
```