# Show datepicker based on culture?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am continuing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235989), since I didn't get full answer.

Questions:

1. *Based on the culture, do the day of first week can change?*
2. *If it's so, how to show the datepicker based on the culture?*

I"m using [Twitter Bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

To show the week number you should use [`calendarWeeks`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#calendarweeks) option and set it to `true` as by default it's `false`. To set the start day of the week, refer to option [`weekStart`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#weekstart):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#date').datepicker({
     calendarWeeks: true; // Whether or not to show week numbers
     weekStart: 0; // Day of the week start. 0 for Sunday; 1 for Monday
   });
});
```

Read more about options and settings in [Bootstrap-Datepicker Documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)

#### [Localization](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html)

The plugin supports *i18n* for the month and weekday names and the `weekStart` option. The default is *English (“en”);* other available translations are available in the `js/locales/` directory, simply include your desired locale after the plugin. To add more languages, simply add a key to `$.fn.datepicker.dates`, before calling `.datepicker()`.

Example:

```
$.fn.datepicker.dates['en'] = {
    days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    today: "Today",
    clear: "Clear"
};
```

Right-to-left languages may also include `rtl: true` to make the calendar display appropriately.

Comment: // I already used this....

$('#date').datepicker({
     calendarWeeks: true; // Whether or not to show week numbers
     weekStart: 0; // Day of the week start. 0 for Sunday; 1 for Monday
   });

I want to know based on the country, do week start change ?

Comment: How are you planning to detect from where is the user coming? It's possible to tie this kind of functionality, to the the site's current language? Is your site multilingual?

Comment: I'm worrying to know the week number. Because if week start date change means, the week number of the year also will change I think.. (I'm asking logically.. don't have any proof)... If no, then please give me a detail. because i've to prove myself, if i'm going your way.. If my words are not polite, don't take it in serious. I'm new to english language.. –

Comment: Logically you are correct. The week number will change! If it's important for you to keep week numbers exact among all users then you shouldn't change it based on culture. Just start the week from Monday and it will be fine, I think?