# Week number in shiny dateRangeInput

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to make a shiny `dateRangeInput` display week numbers in the picker? I believe it exists in bootstrap, but I don't see an option in the arguments...?

[image]

Comment: I have no solution but just trying. So instead of dates you want to display week numbers 1- 52?

Comment: No he wants to enable `calendarWeeks: true` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235989/how-to-show-week-number-in-twitter-bootstrap-date-picker

Comment: Thanks @PorkChop dumb me missed the left side week numbers!